# How to aggregate data and find min,max,avg of numeric columns in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to aggregate the data to application and find the min,max,avg of numeric columns

What I have

```
  Application  income   score_1
    ax          800        77
    ax          900        72
    ax          700        62    
    ax          600        55
```

What I need

```
  Application  min(income) max(income)    avg(income)  min(score_1) max(score_1)    avg(score_1)
    ax          800           900              750        62           77           224.75
```

I can write a query as

```
select min(income),max(income),avg(income),min(score_1),max(score_1),avg(score_1)
from table name group by application; --IT WORKS..!!
```

But in the table I have 20 numeric columns where i need to get the statistics of min,max,avg of those into a table. Is there any approach of getting this done rather writing column names manually to get the avg,min ,max

Comment: What version of Postgres are you using?

Comment: No. There is no free lunch here. SQL is an antique language and predates such bells and whistles

Comment: version 9.5 postgresql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are all numeric, so you could do:

```
select application, which,
       min(val), max(val), avg(val)
from t, lateral
     (values ('income', income), ('score_1', score_1)) v(which, val)
group by application, which;
```

This puts the values on separate rows for each column.

[Here](http://rextester.com/MKQVN31457) is a rextester.

Comment: I got an error "syntax error at or near "(" ..Some issue with open and closed brackets..

Comment: @user8545255 . . . The code works.  I have included a rextester example.

Answer (score 0):

I like Gordon Linoff answer, but I keep getting *cannot evaluate expression outer(.) in inline table definition*.

So my approach was to make big query with a python:

```
columns = ['income','score_1']
functions = ['max','avg','min']

query_list = []
for func in functions:
  subquery = [f"SELECT '{func}'"]
  for col in columns:
    subquery.append(f"    ROUND({func}({col}),2) as {col}")
  query_list.append(",\n".join(subquery) + "\nFROM table_name")
query = "\nUNION\n".join(query_list)

spark.sql(query).show()
```